# clustering websphere mq

Tags: replication, message-queue, ibm-mq

is it possible to establish bi-directional replication on webspehre mq queues so it would work like the db clusters where data is replicated to all of the member instances
imagine following scenario:

queue managers

```
QM1  
DESTINATION.QUEUE  
RESPONSE.QUEUE  

QM2  
DESTINATION.QUEUE   
RESPONSE.QUEUE
```

applications

```
application A issues **put** on DESTINATION.QUEUE@QM1 

application B issues **get** on DESTINATION.QUEUE@QM2

application B sends response **put** RESPONSE.QUEUE@QM2

application A gets response **get** RESPONSE.QUEUE@QM1
```

I am not asking about transmission queues but rather about bi-directional replication where all of the queues are local but constantly updated like db clusters I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMQ does no provide this level of replication.  There are implementations where replication is performed to a secondary site for disaster recovery but these are not bi-directional. The primary and secondary sites cannot both be active at the same time.

It is possible for an application to publish across multiple QMgrs and to subscribe on any QMgr to receive that publication.  The reply is either addressed directly to the requestor or is published on a topic where the requestor is subscribed.